# SQL query consistently selects a non-matching row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm storing an md5 hash in both a cookie and a database. I have a function, `validate_cookie()`, that reads this cookie and queries the database to find the user associated with this hash.

`validate_cookie()` calls another function `get_user_data()` to do the actual querying.`get_user_data()` gets called by a few other functions and scripts, so the query it sends is pretty general. Here's the function:

```
function get_user_data($info,$password=Null,$source=Null)
{
  if(!$source)
    {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($info)."' OR `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($info)."' OR `cookie`='".mysql_real_escape_string($info)."'"; //Check to see if $info matches any column
    }
  else { $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `".mysql_real_escape_string($source)."_token` ='".mysql_real_escape_string($info)."'";} //we got a social token
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  if($result)
    {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      if($password)
    {
      if(crypt($password, $row['password']) == $row['password']) //password matching
        {
          return $row;
        } else {return "Password does not match!";}
    }
      else { return $row; }
    } 
  else { return "Could not get result from database!";}
}
```

The important query in this case is inside of the `if(!source){}` block. With the way `validate_cookie()` calls `get_user_data()` this query becomes (and I have tested that it does become this):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '8sd8sdvsasdliwerhnbzo823' OR `email`='8sd8sdvsasdliwerhnbzo823' OR `cookie`='8sd8sdvsasdliwerhnbzo823'
```

Because `id` is an int field and everything in `email` goes through validation, the only row that should be selected from this query are those with a matching `cookie` field.

However, whether calling this query from a PHP script or manually from PHPMyAdmin, this will always select both the target row and one other: a test case that only has `NULL` in it's `cookie` field. Changing the hash slightly (so that it shouldn't be matching anything at all) still selects this same test case.

Is my query malformed in a way I don't grasp? Are there some arcane uses of `OR` that allows `NULL` fields to be matched? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Before I get told that I should really be using `mysqli`, yes, I know that. `mysql` is the boss's orders.

Comment: The test case has `NULL` for all 3 of those fields, or just the cookie field?  Given that any input results in the same test case output, there must be a condition that is being met.  `OR` requires that one of the 3 conditions you have listed is met.

Comment: Use limit 1, young one.

Comment: you said it had `cookie=null` but what's in the `id` and `email` field of the incorrectly matched row?

Comment: You sure there's no occurrence of '8sd8sdvsasdliwerhnbzo823' in any of the other fields in your test row?

Comment: are you sure of your value for `$source` and it's not hitting the `else` condition of that `if` statement?  I'm not sure it's safe to assume that `NULL===false`.  It may not be the problem here, but it's safer to do `is_null($source)` or make the default `$source=false` and do `if ($source===false)`

Comment: For `email` it has a valid email address, and `id` is 3 (it was the third entry).  The string I gave you guys (8sd8sdvs...) is not any particular string, just a placeholder. Yes, I'm quite sure that there are no other instances of the token, checked many times.

Also, I'm sure that it is not hitting the else condition, since `mysql_query()` would return false since there is no `_token` column, only `$source.'_token'` columns, resulting in an error.

Comment: Also, `LIMIT 1` will only return the test case, because it's comes ordered first. Also, it seems like too much of a hack, what if the same conditions get met and more than one row starts returning and the wrong one gets chosen? Whoops, just logged somebody into somebody else's account.

Comment: Ok.  So.... your `where` has three conditions.  Figure out which one of those (email, cookie, id) is selecting the row by process of elimination.  It is matching something otherwise you wouldn't be getting that row back.  Or... dump that query to the screen immediately before you query to make sure it is what it should be.  I trust the database.  And yeah, `limit 1` is not the way to fix this problem.  The test row matches for some reason.  I would go through and make sure everything is behaving how it should, has the info it should, etc.

Comment: Do you want to try and make an sqlfiddle that shows your query behaving like that with the data you have?  If you can do that, I bet you can get an answer within minutes.  I have a feeling it has to do with the PHP, too, though.

Comment: I made a sqlfiddle: [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a24f/3)

The only problem is that it works. I know it's not the PHP because feeding the query directly into the SQL prompt (PHPMyAdmin) yields the same results.

Comment: Here, I exported the table this time, and took out any sensitive information. Now I get the results that I've been talking about: [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b0832/1)

Comment: lookie:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b0832/10/0  omfg.... the ID of the test row starts with 3... your hash starts with 3...  it's converting the type and taking the 3.  i knew comparing that string to an integer wasn't "ideal" or "best practices" but i didn't think that was the issue.  cast email, id and cookie as their proper column datatypes or something.

Comment: Aw jaysus, that _is_ the problem. Thanks man, I can take it from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b0832/10/0

It is converting your *hash* to an *integer*.  Your test ID is 3.  Your hash starts with 3.  It is making those equal.

```
select cast('3b38f280e0203d7998a0d0898095ed56' as unsigned) as x
```

**yields 3**

fix it like this:

```
SELECT id, email, password, cookie,

case when `email`  = '3b38f280e0203d7998a0d0898095ed56' then 'email'
     when `id`     = '3b38f280e0203d7998a0d0898095ed56' then 'id'
     when `cookie` = '3b38f280e0203d7998a0d0898095ed56' then 'cookie'
     else 'else' end as wtf
FROM `users`
WHERE  
    cast(`id` as char) = '3b38f280e0203d7998a0d0898095ed56' or
    `email`  = '3b38f280e0203d7998a0d0898095ed56' or
    `cookie` = '3b38f280e0203d7998a0d0898095ed56'
```

And that will still work if you pass in an ID = 3

Comment: wow, I overread "... id is an int field ...", and all other db systems I know, would give a sql error like "cant convert '3b..' into integer" or so. I am lucky, that i never had such a prob. with my mySql scripts. This one comes on my "remember strange behvior list", thx for that

Comment: It took me a minute to figure this out... if you take a look at the comments under the question, I didn't believe OP that this was a DB issue at all because it was so strange.  I never even asked what the value of `id` was specifically, either.  the sqlfiddle solved it, though.

Answer (score 1):

If and *only* if you are sure that your sql statement evolves to something like:

```
select a,b,[c ...] from mytable where a='something' or b='something' [or ...]
```

with a,b [...] not NULL

you only should get a row with "a" OR "b" not null and beeing 'something'.
if not, you have a problem with your database/system/diriver or what else

sometimes "the others are wrong"
sry to say that, but thats an expieriance i made (in my case php_db2 i just got no result sometimes).

especially - and again - if you are sure how your statement evolves during runtime, if the "native" tool, here mysql admin gives the same - wrong - result, there is a problem, not in your range

if (and it looks like) there is en error within your database/driver/installation you can try to use a workarround like

```
select from ... where (a='som' and a is not null) or (b='som' and b is not null...) and so on
```

think about marking that with a "TODO:waiting for a correct db install" or so

btw: